# fetch data using some condition in strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, strapi

I am creating api using strapi.
i have a situation, i want to fetch data

> where audience_name like '%audienceName%' and created_by = 4;

below is my strapi code

```
findByName: async (ctx) => {
        const audienceName = ctx.params.name;
        return strapi.services.audience.find({
            audience_name: { 'like' : audienceName},
            created_by: ctx.state.user.id
        });
    },
```

but i am not able to get the data it is trowing internal server error as below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you will have to use these two concepts:

- [Available filters](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#filters) - To see how filters with `contains` instead of `%`
- [Deep filtering](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#deep-filtering) - To filters on `User` relation

You will see, params you are trying to send are not in the right format.

Your code should look like this

```
const data = await strapi.services.audience.find({
  audience_name_contains: audienceName,
  created_by: ctx.state.user.id
});
```

Comment: i tried with this code. but i am getting 400 error `Your filters contain a field 'audience_name_contians' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations`

Comment: I missed `_contians` and should be `_contains`